# How to programmatically change the default messages in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to edit the error message for spam in the contact-form-7 plugin in WordPress. As of now it only shows a simple message with 'there was an error trying to send your message', I would like to change this. But I can not figure out where to find the place in the code where this message is sent from. I have found the default message, but once this is changed, this does not do anything. 
Where can I find this?

Comment: have you see the setting in admin panel ?
`wp-admin=>contact=>edit your form=>'here you can see "message" tab'`

Comment: @Dhruv yes, but i want to include a few variables in the message which is not possible via wp admin

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to change the default messages in CF7, one is using the admin cf7 form editor which has a tab 'Messages', while the 2nd way is to hook the 'wpcf7_messages' filter fired by the plugin once all the messages have been set,

```
//give a prioity >10 to ensure you filter hooks after those of the plugin.
add_filter('wpcf7_messages', 'change_spam_filter', 20,1);
function change_spam_filter($msgs){
  $msgs['spam']['default'] = "this is a custom spam message";
  return $msgs;
}
```

this filter only fires on the admin back-end and not on the front-end.  If you need to filter the message when the form is submitted you can hook,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_display_message','',10,2);
function filter_spam_msg($message, $status){
  if('spam' != $status) return $message;
  $message = "this is a custom spam message";
  return $message;
}
```

EDIT: note that as of v5.5 of the CF7 plugin, HTML formatted responses can longer be diplayed on form submission.  To do this you will need to install an extension.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037715/3596672).

Comment: I will give this a try!

Comment: did it work?  Note that the current version of CF7 plugin no longer accepts HTML formatted responses.  To do this you will need to use a plugin.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037715/3596672).