# How to dynamically change contact form 7 submission display message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Would anyone know how to post a link to a page using Wordpress's contact form 7 plug in?

So, after you hit send a "thank you for your message" sign should pop up, I want to put a link in here.

This is where I want to input the page link
[image: This is where I want to input the page link]

Comment: upload you code so we know what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since v5 of the CF7 plugin, it is no longer possible  to display HTML markup text, only simple text will work due to the issue reported [here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/345) and [here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/396)

**EDIT October 2021**: this solution now works again if you install the [Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin extension for CF7.  The plugin will display your HTML formatted response on the front-end when the form is submitted.

**EDIT October 2023** the CF7 plugin keeps changing its code breaking extensions in the process.  The smart grid has now been updated, and can submit HTML rich messages with the following filter,

```php
add_filter( 'cf7sg_submission_response', 'html_response', 10, 4 );
function html_response( $msg, $status, $data, $cf7key ) {
  if( 'my-form' === $cf7key && 'mail_sent' === $status){
      $msg= 'Hello click <a href="#here">here</a>';
  }
  return $msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**March 2022:** Smart Grid-layout plugin mentioned does not solve the issue, messages are still just plain text.

Currently only solution is https://contactform7.com/2016/01/27/html-is-not-allowed-in-messages/

But it may require alot of re-work depending how custom your implementation is.

**September 2022:**
I rebuilt it using https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Sample:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function ( event ) {
var status = event.detail.status;
if ( status === 'spam' ) {}...
```

Comment: Smart grid works again as of v4.15.5