# allow html tags in contact form 7 success mesage (wpcf7-messages[mail_sent_ok])

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7, elementor

i want to use html in success message.

i try this but not working.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_sent_ok', 'my_succs_message_alter', 1, 2);
function my_succs_message_alter($message, $args){
    $message = htmlspecialchars_decode($message);
    return $message;
}
```

my purpose; after submit show elementor template. But if subject == "aa" show aa template, if subject == "bb" show bb template.. etc. I do it. I print it in success message. just one problem "allow html".

Comment: There is no filter `wpcf7_mail_sent_ok`

Comment: what is the filter for mail_sent_ok

Comment: `wpcf7_mail_sent` https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/56bae206ca44753b43d832dfeafdbf9c44f6c0ff/includes/submission.php#L102

Comment: This question has alreayd been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694718/how-to-dynamically-change-contact-form-7-submission-display-message/65037715#65037715).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer:

php:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_display_message', function($msg){
  $custom_html_message = '<h2>html code..</h2>';
  return htmlentities($custom_html_message);
}, 10, 2);
```

js:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        const successMessage = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output');
        const htmlMessage = htmlEntitiesDecode(successMessage.innerText);
        successMessage.innerHTML = htmlMessage;
    }, 200);
}, false );

function htmlEntitiesDecode(str) {
    return jQuery('<textarea />').html(str).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement @Gökhan Lüleci's answer, which is very good.
I adapted it to use markdown instead html in code.
So you can use the wpcf7 admin message tab without change.
And [br] to add line break.

In your theme files :

functions.php (to add showdown library)

```
wp_enqueue_script(
   'showdown',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/showdown.min.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0',
   true
);
```

scripts.js

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
        wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
            const successMessage = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output');

            var messageOrigin = successMessage.innerText;


            var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
            text      = messageOrigin.replace("[br]", "\n"),
            htmlMessage      = converter.makeHtml(text);

            successMessage.innerHTML = htmlMessage;

        }, 200);
    }, false );
```

In message tab you can use markdown:

```
#### Error[br]Un ou plusieurs champs contiennent une erreur. Veuillez vérifier et essayer à nouveau.
```

Become

```
<h4>Error</h4>
<p>Un ou plusieurs champs contiennent une erreur. Veuillez vérifier et essayer à nouveau.<p>
```